# How to create a multiple window GUI in Qt

Tags: qt

I am very new to this, it's my first GUI project. I want to create a GUI in Qt that has multiple windows in which I have buttons that take me from a window to another. Also, across these windows, I will be passing data.
I am using Qt Designer, and I was wondering what would be the best way to do this. Do I create multiple Main Windows for example? Or should they be as Widgets? Or some other way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main window is one by definition. If you need to create multiple windows however the simplest thing to do is to create a new widget without any parent and show it with show().

```
QWidget *fstWin = new QWidget(nullptr);
QWidget *scdWin = new QWidget(nullptr);
fstWin->show();
scdWin->show();
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html

Answer (score -1):

Your question is very basic. Seems you started to learn GUI from the beginning and probably the programming at all.
Anyway, you dont need more than one Main Window. This is where your program starts.
All other windows must be created from the designer. They are Dialogs. To add a new Dialog, you need to click on your project (right pane), and select Add New...
From the dialog, just select QT and then Qt Designer Form Class. Follow the Wizard and set the type and name of the dialog.
Finishing the Wizard, will add you three items in the project with the name you selected: Header File, Source file (.cpp) and Form file (.ui).
To show a the newly created form, you need to #include your .h file in the mainwindow.h then you need to create a member variable of type "your newly created class" in MainWindow class.
To show the new dialog, just use the function .show() from the member variable. To show the dialog in modal state, use the .exec() function of the member variable.
To pass data between windows, you need to make corresponding methods in your newly created class.
But, just before doing all this stuff, I advise you to take some lessons about Object Oriented Programming. You have to know, what is Class, Object, Member and Field/Variable
Or it will be very hard for you learn more.

Comment: _All other windows must be created from the designer. They are Dialogs._ This is simpy not true.

Comment: In the terms of the question (using QT Designer), IT IS TRUE.  Do you think he can create widgets and dialogs without a designer, at this stage ? I doubt.

Comment: _Do you think he can create widgets and dialogs without a designer, at this stage?_ I try to stay away from assumptions. The goal of Stack overflow is not to help a particular person, but to allow the community to create a knowledge base in form of a Q&A available to anyone. No one could guess the level of knowledge of the futute readers, so the provided answers should strive for accuracy. It is a whole other story, that the question is too broad and as such it should not be answered in the first place.